# Multiple select format in drop down with different options Using TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE editor.
Is it possible to have two(multiple) selectformat with different options as shown like below image?
[image]

Please suggest us, If there is any option or example.

Thank you.